# Tensorflow Dataset - Session crashed after using all avilable RAM when trying to obtain the list of images from loaded dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I loaded `Food101` Dataset from tesnsorflow dataset, and then preprocess it and batch it to train a model. The test_data I obtained as below format:
<PrefetchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))>

There are 25250 images in the test_data set.

Then, after I trained my model, I would like to evaluate my model by picking random images from the test_data set.

So, I decide to obtain lists of images and label from the test_data. After searching around, I decide to use below to obtain list of images and label respectively:

labels = list(map(lambda x: x[1].numpy(), test_data.unbatch()))
images = list(map(lambda x: x[0], test_data.unbatch()))

The one for labels works fine but the images one keep crashing the Colab session (Your session crashed after using all available RAM. )

I am writing to ask whether there is a way to work around to pick random image and label from the test_data set (Prefetch Dataset type) without converting into lists or other way to convert it to list without crashing. It seems that tf.data.take(n) will take the n smaples from the dataset but I am unable to find a way to randomly pick one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is trying to load all of the images into memory when you call `list(...)`.

In order to get an element you indeed need to use `tf.data.take()`, but to get a *random* one, you have to call `tf.data.Dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer_size)` before. (You should also call this before `tf.data.Dataset.prefetch()`). See the [docs for the shuffle method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle).

Note: If you just want to evaluate performance on a test dataset, consider using `model.evaluate()`. [Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate)

Answer (score 0):

After testing through few hours, I get a work around method to do what I want:

1. Generate aa Int in the range(0, len(test_data)) (e.g. `random.randint()`)
2. Use the `shard` method of tf.Dataset

i.e. random_sample = test_data.shard(num_shard=len(test_data), index=randint)

In this case, I am able to pull random samples without crashing my colab seesion all the time. And I need not to keep shuffling the test dataset and use `take` method